# Xpath selection doesn't select url

Tags: php, xpath

I would like to get all href links that contain mediaid in itself. Usually, the xpath I am using works, but not in this case. What am I missing?

Thanks for your time.

DIV:

```
<div class="download"><span class="downloads">25746</span><a href="/download/?type=1&mediaid=205234">Skini titl</a></div>
```

URL:
`https://titlovi.com/titlovi/?prijevod=cobbler&jezik=hrvatski|cirilica|srpski&t=1&g=2014&sort=9`

Xpath

```
//a[contains(@href,"mediaid")]
```

Comment: The given url cannot be correct, please first check that

Comment: Corrected. Sorry about that

Comment: With these kind of problems and not i.e. using Selenium, always first check if in the source the href is present. When I look via source I cannot find "mediaid". So probably it is loaded via some js.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. When I open view source, I can find mediaid `view-source:https://titlovi.com/titlovi/?prijevod=cobbler&jezik=hrvatski|cirilica|srpski&t=1&g=2014&sort=9`

Comment: Well then there is something strange going on. I really cannot find it. The closest i get is this: <div class="download"><span class="downloads">25749</span><a href="/titlovi/the-cobbler-205234/">Skini titl</a></div>

Comment: Found out it that when I echo the response from curl, everything is loaded but not that, indeed, you were right.

Since I am new to xpath, could you please give me the query to get each that link /titlovi/the-cobbler-205234/ ?

Then I could click on it and get from the main page, I've checked and it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the actual source send by the server does not contain the expected html, but does contains these html-fragments:

```
  <div class="download">
    <span class="downloads">25749</span>
    <a href="/titlovi/the-cobbler-205234/">Skini titl</a>
  </div>
```

you could use the following XPath:

```
//div[@class="download"]/a
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much Siebe.